# Don't pass on the patternpath from cloudfront to origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution which I am using to manage directing traffic to different components of my application.

`/*` goes to an S3 bucket hosting my client

`/api/*` goes to an API gateway

However, it seems that the `/api/` part is passed on to my API gateway function, so rather than `CFront://api/action` proxying to `APIGateway://action`, cloudfront is proxying `APIGateway://api/action`.

This results in my lambda not being triggered.

Is there a way to ignore the cloudfront path and not forward that to the origin?

Comment: path pattern* Excuse me, it's 3am here and I am seeing spirals

Comment: The question I've marked this as a duplicate of includes S3 origins rather than API Gateway, but the answer is the same regardless of origin.  CloudFront can prepend a string to the path (the Origin Path setting, under Origins), but it cannot remove path components without help from Lambda@Edge, which uses Lambda functions to manipulate headers, the path, and/or the query string.

Comment: Or, you could simply deploy your API stage as `/api`, of course, so that API Gateway expects the same spurious string at the beginning.

Comment: I have chosen to preappend `/api` to my API Gateway, thanks